# How did I get a segmentation fault here while using vectors in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{
    vector<int> vect;
    vect[0]=1;
    vect[1]=1;
    vect[2]=1;

    for (int x : vect) 
        cout << x << " "; 

    return 0; 
}
```

I would like to know my fault here. I am new to c++ programming. Vectors is a very new concept to me.

Comment: You create a `vector` of size `0`, then try to access three elements from it. This is UB. If you want three elements, then use `vect.resize(3)`, or use `push_back` to add elements.

Comment: You cannot overwrite `vect[0] = 1` because 0th element doesnt exist yet. Use `push_back` instead.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).  The appropriate headers are `<vector>` and `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vect` is an empty vector, so indexing into it invokes undefined behavior.

You could allocate enough space for `vect`, like this:

```
vector<int> vect(3);
```

Or you could `push_back` the elements:

```
vector<int> vect;
vect.push_back(1);
vect.push_back(1);
vect.push_back(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the elements at the positions `1`, `2`, and `3` however they do not exist yet.

To insert to new element try the method `push_back`:

```
vect.push_back(1);
vect.push_back(1);
vect.push_back(1);
```

Another option is to create a vector with three zeros:

```
std::vector<int> vect(3, 0);
vect[0]=1;
vect[1]=1;
vect[2]=1;
```

Or much more simple, create a vector with size 3 and all elements are assigned with 1:

```
std::vector<int> vect(3, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`vect` does not have allocated storage, so there isn't an arena to put the values on, hence undefined behaviour. You can get the allocated space of a container with [capacity()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), so in your case, `vect.capacity()` will return 0.

Furthermore, [operator []](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) won't check the boundaries, so it will try to access to [ 2 ], even if its [size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is 0. To access checking boundaries use [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Considering that, to solve the problem you will have to allocate space for the container (in your case, `std::vector`), that is,  reserve an area of memory just for `vect`, `vector` offers different ways to modify its size, such as [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), etc.

Note: if possible, avoid the use of [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [`<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)